# CodeIgniter- Perform action when query returns no results

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have a model which accepts username and password and returns other user related details such as name and total points in an array.
In case query returns blank(if records not found), it should redirect back to the login page.
Here i have also added the empty array as "$results=array()".
Please guide where is bug in my code. In all cases it returns as true.

My model:

```
function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $query=$this->db->get('users');
    $results=array();
        foreach($query->result() as $rows)
            {
                $results[]= array(
               'first_name'   => $rows->first_name,
               'phone'        => $rows->phone,
               'total_points' => $rows->total_points,
                                );
            }

    return $results;
    }
```

And here is my controller:

```
public function validate_credentials()
{
    $this->load->model('Membership_model');
    $query['result']=$this->Membership_model->validate();
    if(empty($query))  //if $query is blank it should redirect to home page
    {
        redirect('http://localhost/luckyDraw/en');
    }
    else echo "details received";
    // else
    // {

    //  $data=array(
    //      'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    //      'is_logged_in' => true,
    //          );
    //  $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    //  $this->load->view('members_area',$query);
    // }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you var_dump($query) only to make sure it is as empty as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($this->db->get_where('users', array('username' => $this->input->post('username', true), 'password' => $this->input->post('password', true))->num_rows() > 0)
{
 // write your foreach statement here (I think you shouldn't write foreach statement to fetch user data, you can use `row_array`)
}
else
{
 // if there is no result
}
```

Tip: Keep passwords encrypted in your database. You can use `password_hash` and `password_verify`. This is very important. Please see [here](http://php.net/manual/ref.password.php).

Answer (score 0):

Fetching object and then converting same data into array.
I didn't get what and why you have done this in your model and Also Why you have `echo` the `received` message on a controller Send that to the view and display.

#### What you should do?

I see you are fetching single user data from the database. Then use `$query->row_arary();`

Your Query & Model Code Should Be:

```
$this->db->select('first_name,phone,total_points');
$this->db->where('username,$this->input->post('username')');
$this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
$query=$this->db->get('users');

// Now To get the User data Array in result:
$user_data = $query->row_array();
return $user_data; // return the data to the controller:
```

Your Controller Code:

```
public function validate_credentials()
{
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $user_data = $this->membership_model->validate();
    
    if(isset($user_data) && !empty($user_data)){
        
         $this->load->view('your_view'.['msg'=>'details received']);
        
    } else {        
        //if $query is blank it should redirect to home page        
    }
}
```

If you want to echo the user data at the view side then do this:

```
<?php 
echo $user_data['first_name']; // Same with other data.
?>
```